# Rails multistep form update instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just watched the railscasts for [multistep forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms), and I now have a multistep form that works great when creating a new instance, but updating and editing does not work, it does the multistep but when I click continue on the last step it just does not update, and it seems the session gets lost...

This is the controller... If I use

```
session[:location_params].deep_merge!(params[:location]) if params[:location]
```

an error happens that states that deep_merge cannot be done...

```
  def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    session[:location_params] = @location
    @location.current_step = session[:location_step] = @location.steps.first
  end

  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.current_step = session[:location_step]
    if params[:back_button]
      @location.previous_step
    elsif @location.last_step?
      @location.save if @location.all_valid? and @location.changed?
    else
      @location.next_step
    end
    session[:location_step] = @location.current_step
    if @location.created_at_changed?
      flash[:success] = "Location updated!"
      session[:location_step] = session[:location_params] = nil
      redirect_to @location
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: It's not saved because it's not valid I suppose. I suggest you to add [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) and look at variable states. That would be _much_ faster then waiting for a proper answer.

Comment: I did had debug to look at session and params, see what was going on... but then I decided to use http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx . Thank you Vadim

Comment: I think you should post that as answer and accept it(since you don't need help anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using FormToWizard jquery library, you can download it [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx).

Its cleaner and makes the views very clean to work with and easily maintenable, does not change anything on the controllers!